# Not able to add DATA-tire to my application AWS (Configuration error while adding with snapshot)

Tags: amazon-web-services

i am trying to add `DATA-tire` to my application in `AWS` using `snapshot` of my `RDS instance`
as follows shown in the below image

[please check configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgTRR.png)

when it validates the following error is a rising

[please check the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQM1u.png)

please help me with this i got stuck here since 3 days

Answer (score 0):

This may be a compatible issue between the DB Engine, Engine Version and Instance Class of your snapshot and the new instance you are trying to create from that snapshot.  Either you have to create new instance exactly same as your snapshot or make sure the the Instance Class supports DB Engine and Engine Version as mentioned in the below link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html